# Просмотр вперёд

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такое регулярное выражение:

```
abc(?=d)e
```

Есть такая строка: abcde.
Почему регулярка не срабатывает? abc нашли, далее просматриваем вперёд, d есть, и в конце e.

Comment: Потому что с точки зрения регулярки перед е у вас стоит символ с, который не является d. Для подтверждения попробуйте abc.(?=d)e.

Comment: Всё равно не срабатывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, что происходит для регулярки `abc(?=d)e` по строке `"abcde"`.

1. Вход: `"abcde"`. Результат: `<пустой>`.
2. Из исходной строки в результат выбираются первые три буквы - они точно есть. Вход: `"de"`. Результат: `"abc"`.
3. Далее идет просмотр вперед буквы `'d'` - `(?=d)`. Просмотр вперед не двигает курсор по входной строке. Вход: `"de"`. Результат: `"abc"`.
4. Далее пытаемся выбрать букву `'e'` из входной строки, но у нас на очереди еще только `'d'`. Матчинг останавливается, расходимся.

То, что вы, возможно, ожидаете получить, можно получить регулярным выражением `abc(?=d).e`.
Точка выберет из входной строки букву `'d'`, затем отработает буква `'e'` и поиск успешно закончится, вернув `"abcde"`.

Правда, того же результата можно было добиться и просто выражением `abcde`. Непонятно, зачем вам здесь просмотр вперед. Он обычно нужен, когда за искомым выражением что-то должно быть, но попасть в результат не должно.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ! А если регулярное выражение полностью состоит из просмотров вперёд, например: (?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).* . То начиная с первого символа идёт просмотр вперёд?

Comment: Да. Только выражение `(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?!.\s).* ` выглядит бессмысленно. Вы сначала ищите в начале строки любой символ и цифру, а потом еще раз ищите любой символ и букву. Уже противоречие: цифра и буква одновременно не могут быть на 2-й позиции в строке.

Comment: @PiterPan, просмотр вперед, назад есть позиционные проверки. Они не захватывают символы и проверяют от той позиции, на которой они находятся. Конструкция:  

    (?=1)(?=2)(?=3).

Равносильно:  

    [1-3]

Comment: @ReinRaus, ммм... нет. Не равносильно. [Первый случай](http://rubular.com/r/pMa2Z26X98) и [второй](http://rubular.com/r/QK9R2cR8ew).

Проверка вида `(?=1)(?=2)(?=3).` как бы говорит: "сначала должна быть 1 и в то же время 2, и 3, верни этот символ" .

Comment: Вот `(?=[1-3]).` - равносильно `[1-3]`.

Но лучше не надо )

Comment: Тьфу. Точно.  
Хотел наглядный пример привести и закосячил :-)  

    ^(?=[A-Z])(?!(?:[^_]*_){2,})\w+$

Не очень наглядно, но так можно делать простую проверку соответствия текста условиям. Например, здесь проверяется, что первый символ это заглавная буква, и что в тексте не более одного знака _.

Comment: @Nofate, этот пример указывается в http://html5pattern.com/Passwords как проверка того, что в пароле есть хотя бы одна строчная, заглавная буквы и цифра, и ход работы этой регулярки немного не ясен.

Comment: @PiterPan, вы привели здесь выражение:

    (?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?!.\s).*

а на указанном сайте

    (?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*

и тут есть большая разница.

Выражение работает так:

 1. `(?=.*\d)` Проверяем, что впереди в строке есть любые символы и одна цифра. 
 2. `(?=.*[a-z])` Проверяем, что впереди в строке есть любые символы и строчная буква.
 3. `(?=.*[A-Z])` Проверяем, что впереди в строке есть любые символы и заглавная буква.
 4. `(?!.*\s)` Проверяем, что впереди в строке есть любые символы и нет пробела (негативный look-ahead).
 5. `.*` Захватываем всю строчку.

Comment: А из вашего выражения следует, что все символы - цифра, строчная и заглавная буквы - находятся одновременно на второй позиции от начала поиска.

Comment: @Nofate, а по 1 пункту, он как-бы просматривает, является ли 1 символ в строке любым и цифрой, а далее он не меняет позиции при просмотре, или когда проверил первый символ, смещается на него?

Comment: @PiterPan, еще раз. Есть выражение `(?=.*\d)`. Любое количество любых символов и цифра. Грубый алгоритм для него такой. Сначала оно проверит, не является ли первый символ цифрой, при неудаче - проверит, не является ли первый символ произвольным символом, а второй - цифрой. При неудаче - являются ли первые 2 символа произвольными, а третий - числом. И так далее, пока не кончится строка или не будет найдена цифра. 

Если поиски цифры закончатся успехом, регулярное выражение вернется в начало строки и займется следующим look-ahead блоком.

Comment: @Nofate, понял. Огромное спасибо за подробные объяснения!